# conflicting versions for project dependency with Vue3 and Vuetify3

Tags: vuejs3, vuetifyjs3

I want to install Vue3 and Vuetify without version conflict using npm create vue@latest.

I I installed npm create vue@latest for the project.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akcfz.jpg)

I wanted to use vueteify, so I installed it using vue add vueteify.
Preset chose Vuetify 3 - Vite (preview).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ad3PZ.jpg)

How can I avoid version conflicts?

I also tried a new installation to prevent version conflicts.
The latest version provided by vuetify, "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.5.0", "vite": downgrade to "^5.0.0", and install using vue add vuetify, showed the same version conflict.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

`npm create vue` uses [create-vue](https://github.com/vuejs/create-vue), `vue add` uses [vue-cli](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli) which is now deprecated.
You can either manually install vuetify in the create-vue app by following https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/#existing-projects, or create a new one with `npm create vuetify`